# Transfer multi-website content between staging and production

Tags: magento2, multi-website

I need to migrate some content from staging environment to production without replacing the whole database. I didn't found any tool or extension for Magento 2 that can help me resolve this issue.

I am having Magento 2 project setup on 3 different environments:

1. Local server - development environment (merge features to develop branch)
2. Staging server - develop branch
3. Production server - master branch

We are doing some releases (using git flow) of the code regularly but we created **2 additional websites (stores)** on the staging server who are going to use new domain names. After that our client starts to create new content for the staging websites as follow:

1. CMS pages
2. CMS blocks
3. Widgets
4. New category tree
5. Product attributes (also add new options for some attributes)
6. Import products for updating some attributes

We can't switch the entire database because we are going to loose customers, orders, reports etc.

How you transfer such a content from one instance to another. I was thinking of creating module with setup script to create new websites,stores and store views but I can't put all the content in that setup.

From Magento core team still don't know the deployment steps to production server...

[Check it in official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_deploy.html) Nothing mentioned about content migrating from one instance to another.

Comment: Without going in detail, you may have to do like on Magento 1. Create a module which take care of such data migration and using the InstallData and InstallSchema classes. They should implement `\Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface` or `\Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface`

Comment: This is not an option for me. The content is already created manually. I think I can't use `InstallDataInterface` for my case.

Comment: Hi @MiroslavPetroff, Did you get a solution or any module for this? I have also the same requirement